# How to render angular component from string

Tags: angular

I have list of rows from where i want to make a table.

```
rows = [
{
  emplName: "Sabbir",
  company: "Ericson",
  dob: "1990-02-02",
  edit: "<app-edit></app-edit>"
},
{
  emplName: "Sakib",
  company: "NewZen Ltd",
  dob: "1989-01-01",
  edit: "<app-edit></app-edit>"
}
]
```

Table format is given below

```
Name    Company   DOB          Edit
Sabbir  Ericson   1990-02-02   <app-edit></app-edit>
```

In Edit column i want to render a component name "EditComponent" whose selector i specified in the string "app-edit".How can i render this string as a component so that i can view its template in the table cell?

This is my EditComponent

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-edit',
templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./edit.component.css']
})

export class EditComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
  }

 editModel(){
  alert('hello');
}

}
```

and this is my edit.component.html template

```
<button (click)="editModel()">Edit</button>
```

I want to render this button in my table cell.

Comment: In your `Edit` Column place a `[routerLink]="['routername']"` there and then add place `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` whereever you want to load the component. This might help you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to load your components dynamically.

Since you have not uploaded your attempt at this, there is really nothing I can help you with, except for providing you this link, which should solve what you are trying to achieve.

Have a look [here](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) on how to load components dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer the following link

[Dynamically Generate Angular Components](https://www.arka.com/blog/dynamically-generate-angular-components-from-external-html)

Comment: Unfornately that tutorial doesn't work anymore since Angular 9 because of Ivy.